# Build runnable and container version of jar in maven

Tags: maven, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a package which is deployed to a container which provides log4j. But at the same time the package has a main class and a user may execute it from command line.

My question is how to build the jar which:

1. use the log4j provided by the container (normally I would mark it with `<scope>provided</scope>`)
2. is executable from command line (which means it must contain all dependencies including log4j)

It doesn't necessarily be only one jar file in the end. It is possible to have one jar for deployment and another one for manual execution. In that case but both jars must be built by a single invocation of maven.

I think it could be managed by two `<execution>`s of maven-assembly-plugin but I really don't know how to pack the log4j dependency only in one of them.

Comment: As far as I can see, you'll need two jars for this. You can't create a jar that has log4j and doesn't have log4j at the same time.

Comment: Do you know how to build two jars with different dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the shade or the assembly plugin. Unfortunately, the examples for both of these are terrible.  I'm sure you can find better documentation on SO than their official site.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage it using the shade plugin. My setup is:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>standalone</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>***path.to.main.class***</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <finalName>${artifactId}-standalone</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>container</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>log4j</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```